# Change one property in CSS

Tags: css

I have this CSS style:

```
.bx--text-area:disabled {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #e5e5e5;
    color: black;
    height: 6.25rem;
}
```

And I want to change just the color property without copy-pasting the whole style in to my css stylesheet.

How can I do that? Is that possible?

Comment: Am I missing something here? Can't you just append `.bx--text-area:disabled { color: newColor; }`?

Comment: `.bx--text-area:disabled { color: white; }` add this to your stylesheet, if it isnt applied you need to check the loadorder of your css or just add `!important`

Comment: Don't use `!important` if you have access to the whole stylesheet like you've mentioned you have. See why: https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try**

```
.body{
  color:black;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add common class to elements and add other class with specific property for that

```css
.commanClass
{
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.bg1
{
  background: red;
}
.bg2
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="commanClass bg1">  
</div>

<div class="commanClass bg2">  
</div>
```